# Chrome bookmarks have totally disappeared from my system

Tags: google-chrome, backup, data-recovery, bookmarks

I logged on to Chrome today, and my entire bookmarks, 1000's of entries, was gone. That was several years of detailed research and it's gone just like that.

Is there any way to get the Chrome bookmarks data file to be turned back a day or two?  I'm really suffering with this one.

I also tried doing a Windows restore to a couple days ago, but had no luck.

Comment: some lessons are best learned the hard way: backups. please provide more information about your operating system etc.

Comment: Is there a `Bookmarks` file in `%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`? What is its size?

Comment: Do you "sign in" to Chrome and sync between devices?

Comment: This happened to me a few days ago after a chrome update, did not delete all, but most, yes I had a recent backup of the bookmarks file.

Answer (score 0):

Lost all mine, thousands of bookmarks, finally found workable solution on a google forum, here it is, kudos to Leo, all other solutions failed:

Leo.MeltLevel 2
9/4/12
In win7 your bookmarks are stored in C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
There are two files here:
Bookmarks and Bookmarks.bak
Right click on one of them and click "restore previous versions". It will look for other versions for a while and give you 3 previous versions to choose from. Choose the latest one. Do the same thing for the other file. Now turn on Chrome and your bookmarks are back. If they are not back, try restoring and older version of those files.
I would advise saving a copy of both files to a separate folder(a thumb drive too) every few months.